# In my to-do-list the delete/remove task function does not work. Any Ideas Why?

Tags: javascript, json

This is an application for a basic to do list using vanilla JavaScript. I have been able to get everything to work but i am unable to click the delete icon in order for it to delete an element. Can anyone see any mistakes in the removeTask function? Or maybe a problem occurred when i decided to clearTasks/ delete from Local Storage?

```
//Define UI variables
const form = document.getElementById('task-form');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');
const filter = document.getElementById('filter');
const taskInput = document.getElementById('task');

//load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();
//function
function loadEventListeners(){
  //DOM load event
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getTasks )
  //add task
  form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
  //remove task evernt
  taskList.addEventListener('click', removeTask)
  //Clear task event
  clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clearTasks)
  //filter tasks event
  filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterTasks)

}
//Get task from local Storage
function getTasks(){
  let tasks;
  if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null){
    tasks = [];
  } else{
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  }

  tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    //create list element
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  //add class
  li.className = 'collection-item';
  //text node create and append to li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
  // add link element
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  //ad class
  link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
  //add icon html
  link.innerHTML = '<i class ="fa fa-remove"></li>';
  //append the link to li
  li.appendChild(link);
  //append to ul
  taskList.appendChild(li);
  });
}
//Add task
function addTask(e){
  if(taskInput.value === ''){
    alert('You Have Not Inputed Anything. Please Add A Task');
  }
  //create list element
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  //add class
  li.className = 'collection-item';
  //text node create and append to li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
  // add link element
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  //ad class
  link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
  //add icon html
  link.innerHTML = '<i class ="fa fa-remove"></li>';
  //append the link to li
  li.appendChild(link);
  //append to ul
  taskList.appendChild(li);
  //local storage
  storeToLocalStorage(taskInput.value);
  //clear input
  taskInput.value = '';
  e.preventDefault();
}
//store to local
function storeToLocalStorage(task){
  let tasks;
  if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null ){
    tasks = [];
  }else{
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  }
  tasks.push(task);

  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}
//remove task
function removeTask(e){
  if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      //REMOVE FROM LS
      removeTask(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
    }
  }
}

//remove from LS
function removeTask(taskItem){
  let tasks;
  if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null ){
    tasks = [];
  }else{
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  }
  tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
    if(taskItem.textContent === task){
      task.splice(index, 1);
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}
//clear tasks
function clearTasks(){
  //simpler method
  //taskList.innerHTML = '';

  //faster and better method
  while(taskList.firstChild){
    taskList.removeChild(taskList.firstChild);
  }
  //clear from LS
  clearTasksLs();
}
//clear tasks from LS
function clearTasksLs(){
  localStorage.clear();
}
//Filter tasks
function filterTasks(e){
  const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('.collection-item').forEach(function (task){
    const item = task.firstChild.textContent;
    if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1){
      task.style.display = 'block';
    }else {
      task.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: When you are fetching something with class selector, that returns as array because you can have multiple elements with that class. Try for example taskList[0] OR use ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing the html but you have two methods named removeTask that both accept 1 argument. So how does it know which method to use? You need to either combine them somehow or name them something different.

Comment: Great glad to hear it! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?

Comment: The second function declaration overwrites the first one. That's how it "knows" which one to use.

Comment: You are correct that it overwrites the first one. But that's what's causing his error. It's only removing it from the list in one function and ignoring the function that actually removes it from the DOM.

Comment: @EstherNdung'u could you mark this answer as correct? I'm just a simple man who enjoys seeing my points go up, lol.